# How to rename a file on the SFMC FTP?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, ftp

I am looking for a way to rename a file on the SFMC FTP using an automation. I have tried using the substitution strings %%FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER_BASE%% and %%BASEFILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%% with the "enhanced move and copy" data extract. Sadly it didn't do anything. Is there a way to do this with automation studio or with the API?

Comment: API and SSJS cannot manipulate the sFTP unfortunately, to my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks, @JonasLamberty I have found that out as well. I had to do the extract and then import it and then extract it to be able to change the file name. Its too bad you can't specify file names for the individual tracking extracts.